# difference between django.shortcuts and rest_framework.generics

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

what is difference between two The following sentence

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
```

and

```
from rest_framework.generics import get_object_or_404
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django.shortcuts.get_object_or_404` can raise errors other than `Http404` (namely `TypeError`, `ValueError`, and `ValidationError`) in case that the type of the kwarg passed does not match the required types. Hence  `rest_framework.generics.get_object_or_404` is simply wrapping `django.shortcuts.get_object_or_404` such that `Http404` is still raised even in these cases as DRF uses the function internally and the passed data can easily fail to match the required datatypes causing unintended 500 errors.

This can be seen from DRF's [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/61e7a993bd0702d30e3049179000bc7c5f284781/rest_framework/generics.py#L13-L21):

> ```
> from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404 as _get_object_or_404
>
>
> def get_object_or_404(queryset, *filter_args, **filter_kwargs):
>     """
>     Same as Django's standard shortcut, but make sure to also raise 404
>     if the filter_kwargs don't match the required types.
>     """
>     try:
>         return _get_object_or_404(queryset, *filter_args, **filter_kwargs)
>     except (TypeError, ValueError, ValidationError):
>         raise Http404
> ```

Comment: `rest_framework.generics.get_object_or_404` should be better since you are dealing with an API and it would be more likely for wrong types, etc. to be passed to the function. (In normal views such parameters are mostly passed from the url as kwargs and normally path converters should catch incorrect types and give a 404)